# Fortran OpenMP where will the array be allocated

Tags: arrays, fortran, openmp, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have a question about Fortran-OpenMP and allocatable arrays. It's simple: Where will the space be allocated? If I have something like

```
!$omp parallel default(shared) private(arr)
!$omp critical
  allocate( arr(BIGNUMBER) )
!$omp end critical

!do calculations with many arr accesses

!$omp critical
  deallocate( arr )
!$omp end critical
!$omp end parallel
```

will the space be allocated on the stack, or the heap? If it's on the heap, is there a difference between the code above and something like this

```
allocate( arr(BIGNUMBER, nThread) )
!$omp parallel default(shared) private(localArr)
  iThread = omp_get_thread_num()

  localArr => arr(:, iThread)

  !do calculations with many localArr accesses
!$omp end parallel

deallocate( arr )
```

- In the first code, there are two critical regions. I would assume, that they would slow the execution down and not scale very well. (I'm actually not sure if I could just leave them out, because the allocate is thread-save?) But if the array were allocated on the stack, then it should be faster, because of faster access.
- In the second code I am sure to have the array on the heap, which is slower access. But if the array in the first code is allocated on the heap as well, then I'll save the critical reagions + it's only one allocate/deallocate. Should be faster?
- Does the size of the array play any roll in this?
- If it were to be allocated on the heap, is there a way to force an allocation on the stack?

The short question is basically: Which would seem to be the optimal solution for the problem?

Comment: You can do `localArr => arr...` but this means `arr` is shared among the threads. I think you don't want that. The pointer `localArr` will have a copy for each thread, but the contents pointed to will be shared. Changes in one thread to the contents of the array will be reflected in the other threads.

Answer (score 6):

Fortran compilers with OpenMP tend to allocate automatic variable (including arrays) on the stack. When you do explicit allocation I they will be allocated on the heap, but note that Fortran standard does not speak about stack or heap at all, it's up to the compiler.  In Ex. number 1 I would leave the critical sections out, because you are allocating private variables. Regarding to the size, there are sometimes stack overflows due to too large automatic arrays, but this is probably not your case. What is the fastest approach I don't know.

This program allocates arrays on the heap in my compiler

```
integer,parameter :: BIGNUMBER = 100000000
real,dimension(:),allocatable :: arr

allocate( arr(BIGNUMBER) )

!$omp parallel default(shared) private(Arr)
  iThread = omp_get_thread_num()

  arr = 5
  
  print *, arr

!$omp end parallel
deallocate( arr )


end
```

and this one on the stack (and then it crashes)

```
integer,parameter :: BIGNUMBER = 100000000
real arr(BIGNUMBER)

!$omp parallel default(shared) private(Arr)
  iThread = omp_get_thread_num()

  arr = 5
  
  print *, arr

!$omp end parallel


end
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for your explanation. I was not sure with the critical, because of it's synch. After the critical region follows an "!$omp do", and I'm not sure if the start of this does imply a barrier (the arrays need to be allocated before the do-loop starts). So I was taking the "save" route I guess. But the allocation time itself should actually not be that big of a problem, but I'll try to drop the critical and see what happens :) thx.

Comment: OpenMP will allocate on the stack, always. The only way to prevent this is to allocate your array inside the parallel block manually, as the OP did in the first example.

Comment: @Jason There is nothing like "OpenMP will allocate". What allocates or not is the code generated by Fortran compilers. What happens when OpenMP is in effect is outside of standard Fortran. And you are certainly wrong. When the array is allocatable, the private copies will be made on the heap. Yes, even when you allocated before the parallel region and left the privatization on OpenMP.

Comment: @VladimirF Who or what code is making the private copies when allocation is done before the parallel region? Is that hidden in the `!$omp parallel default(shared) private(Arr)` statement?

Comment: @Jason It is. See also this discussion https://forum.openmp.org/viewtopic.php?t=2098  , it also discusses the custom allocators of OpenMP 5.

Comment: Is the following statement the one that you're referring to about arrays allocating on the heap, or is there another one: "Only arrays that are identified as ALLOCATABLE in the !$OMP routine have their PRIVATE copies placed on the HEAP. Allocated arrays supplied as routine arguments do not, unless they are identified as ALLOCATABLE in the omp routine (not tested)."

Comment: Yes, but the whole thread is informative.

Answer (score 3):

OK, Vladimir says most of what I would have said (Not mentioned in the standard, it's totally up to the implementation, why are you using criticals to protect your privates?)

But ... you give the impression that you think that access to memory allocated on the stack is somehow faster than that on the heap. On any typical implementation this is not the case - the access time is the same. *Allocation* of memory on the stack is usually quicker than on the heap, but once it is allocated the time to access it is the same. So I would cut the criticals and go route 1 - it's simpler, keeping things private is good, pointers are bad, and if memory allocation time is your limiting step then you've almost certainly not got enough work in the parallel region to make parallelising it worthwhile.

Comment: I was indeed under the assumption, that memory on the stack is faster accessible than on the heap. Am I confusing this with shared/private now? Access to shared arrays is slower (and I thought that means it's on the heap), while access to private is fast (stack). It is entirely possible I got something backwards here. Also should add, the allocation time is not the problem, it's just a huge amount of access to this big array, so I would like this to be as fast as possible.

Comment: @Cabadath From the point of view of accessing main memory, it does not matter whether you access stack or heap. It is just a region of the main memory, nothing more. Similar for private/shared. What is slow is synchronization, like false sharing, not accessing per se.